# How to redirect (jump) on different section in single Page in Angular

Tags: angular

When using tab on a page and click to jump on that page section in Angular.

```
  scrollToElement($element): void {
    $element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
  }
```

On Anchor Link use **(click)="scrollToElement(publishedResearchSection)"** instead of href.

use #publishedResearchSection on target div

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to make use of fragments in Angular.

So in your code where you call the navigate to method e.g.:

```
this.router.navigate(['/results'], { fragment: 'publishedResearchSection' });
```

add the fragment property pointing to the required id.

And then in your HTML file for that component, add an id to the element you want to scroll to:

```
<div #publishedResearchSection></div>
```

Have a look at [Url creations with fragments](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlCreationOptions#fragment) for more info.